# REPLACE and REPLACE_REGEX SQL

Tags: sql

How to remove the parenthesis and the values as well in sql in an easier way? 
Replace works to remove the parenthesis and replace_regexpr can be used to remove the numbers.

Input String:

```
abcdef12(31)
```

expected output string:

```
abcdef12
```

replace and replace_regexpr

Query sample:

```
select REPLACE_REGEXPR('[123*]' in 'abcdef12(31)') from dummy
```

Input String:

```
abcdef12(31)
```

expected output string:

```
abcdef12
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  What is the issue with your query?

Comment: its SAP HANA DB, the queries removes all numbers and paranthesis,  but need to remove numbers only inside the paranthesis

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the syntax to look like this:

```
select regexp_replace('abcdef12(31)', '[(][^(]*[)]', '')
```

Use the regular expressions to replace both the parentheses and the contents.  The regular expression `'[(][^(]*[)]'` matches the opening parenthesis and the closing parenthesis and everything between them.

In SAP Hana, I think the syntax is:

```
select replace_regex('[(][^(]*[)]' in 'abcdef12(31)' with '')
```

The `with ''` is optional.

Comment: select REPLACE_REGEXPR('[(][^(]*[)]' in 'abcdef12(31)') from dummy ;